# Overload operators in a function without writing body 2 times

Tags: c++, arduino, operator-overloading

Currently, i have this code:

```
void writeLog(__FlashStringHelper* mes){

  Serial.println(mes);

  if(!logfile){
    logfile = SD.open(logpath,FILE_WRITE);
    if(!logfile) return;
  }

  logfile.write(mes);

}

void writeLog(char* mes){

  Serial.println(mes);

  if(!logfile){
    logfile = SD.open(logpath,FILE_WRITE);
    if(!logfile) return;
  }

  logfile.write(mes);

}
```

Is there a way to overload a function to accept char* and __FlashStringHelper* without writing the body 2 times?

Thanks!

Comment: How about using templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, i found a solution!
There is a class that is shipped with Arduino IDE called String. It supports implicit casts from __FlashStringHelper* and char*.

```
void writeLog(String mes){

  Serial.println(mes);

  if(!logfile){
    logfile = SD.open(logpath,FILE_WRITE);
    if(!logfile) return;
  }

  logfile.println(mes);

}

writeLog("A string from RAM");
writeLog(F("A string from flash memory"));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can use templates try this:

```
template <typename T>
void writeLog(T mes) {

    Serial.println(mes);

    if (!logfile) {
        logfile = SD.open(logpath, FILE_WRITE);
        if (!logfile) return;
    }

    logfile.write(mes);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much *exactly* what [template functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) are for! You need only write one template function in your case, as follows:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void writeLog(T mes)
{
    Serial.println(mes);
    if (!logfile) {
        logfile = SD.open(logpath, FILE_WRITE);
        if (!logfile) return;
    }
    logfile.write(mes);
}
```

Then you can call this with an argument of any *valid* type. If you try to call it with an argument type for which there is no compatible version of the `Serial.println` or `logfile.write` calls, then the compiler will give an error. Otherwise, the compiler will generate code for the appropriate **real** function as and when you make a valid call. Thus, your `main` could look something like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    char text[256];
    writeLog(text); // OK: Compiler will generate the code equivalent to your second function
    __FlashStringHelper fsh;
    writeLog(&fsh); // OK: Compiler will generate the code equivalent to your first function
    int p;
//    writeLog(p);  //Error: No suitable versions of "Serial.println()" and "logfile.write()" with an int parameter
    return 1;
}
```

EDIT: If you know that all calls to your function will be made using a *pointer* type as the argument, you could make your template more specific (and thus better detect mis-uses) by specifying the argument as a pointer:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void writeLog(T* mes)
{
//...
```